# Using PHP selection box to choose SQL fields with specific numeric value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Thanks in advance for your help, am still very new to writing code. I am trying to use a selection list to choose a specific date, and from that date, print a list of names for people signed up. The database holds a value of 1 when they are signed up and zero if they are not signed up. The difficulty has arisen in trying to process the date that was input and SELECT the names with the appropriate value in the database. Thanks for any feedback, and apologize in advance for any blatant errors!

```
<form name="whoplaying" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="playdate">
       <option value="playdate1"> September 3, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate2"> September 6, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate3"> September 10, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate4"> September 13, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate5"> September 17, 2014 </option>
    </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Select Playdate">

<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$username = '#####';
$password = '#####';
$db_name = 'signuplist';
$tbl_name = 'signupbydate';
$myusername=$_SESSION['logname']; 

$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name)
     or die ("Couldn't Connect to Server");

     if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {   
         $playdate = $_POST['playdate'];

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($cxn);
           if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, 'SELECT username FROM $tbl_name WHERE $playdate=?')) {

           /* bind parameters for markers */
           mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $playdate);

           /* execute query */
           mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

           /* bind result variables */
           $result=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $playdate);

           /* fetch value */
              while   ($row=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result));
               {                       
                 echo "<table border='1'>
             <table class='center'>
         <tr>
             <th><div style=width:100px>Username</div></th>
                 </tr>";

             extract ($row);
             echo"<tr>\n
             <td>$username</td>
             </tr>\n";
              }
           echo "</table>"; 

           mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  }    

     mysqli_close($cxn);

    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work fine now, thanks for the inspiration to keep trying!

```
<form name="whoplaying" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <select name="playdate">
       <option value="playdate1" > September 3, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate2" > September 6, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate3" > September 10, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate4" > September 13, 2014 </option>
       <option value="playdate5" > September 17, 2014 </option>
    </select>           
       <input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit">

<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$username = '#####';
$password = '#####';
$db_name = 'signuplist';
$tbl_name = 'signupbydate';
$myusername=$_SESSION['logname']; 

$cxn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name)
     or die ("Couldn't Connect to Server");


 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {   
     $playdate = $_POST['playdate'];
     $value='1';
         $query = "select username from $tbl_name where $playdate = ?";
         $stmt = $cxn->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
         $stmt->execute();
         $result = $stmt->get_result();                                      
          echo "<table border='1'>
      <table class='center'>
    <tr>
        <th><div style=width:100px>Firstname</div></th>
        <th><div style=width:100px>Lastname</div></th>
    </tr>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
extract ($row);
echo"<tr>\n
     <td>$username</td>
     <td>$username</td>
     </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";              

 mysqli_close($cxn);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your form is defined wrong. It should be

```
<select name="playdate">
   <option value="Sep 3, 2014">Sep 3, 2014</option>
   <option value="Sep 6, 2014">Sep 6, 2014</option>
   etc...
</select>

$playdate = $_POST['playdate']; // $playdate becomes "Sep 3, 2014"
```

Plus, you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so stop working on this code until you've learned how to avoid that.

Comment: Database columns are 'playdate1', 'playdate2' etc which correspond to the dates listed. I made this change but get no output. I will include the stripslashes and other necessary protections once I get the thing working, thanks.

Comment: that's a horrible database design, then. why not a SINGLE "playdate" field that's a "datetime" type? with your design, you have to have a column for ever possible date, which is just ludicrous.

Comment: I realize it is not ideal, although I do not know how a single playdate 'datetime' field would work when I need an ongoing selection option for every single Wednesday and Saturday only. As I said, I am new to this, and am actually enjoying the very steep learning curve, but it is baby steps. I would love to gain the functionality of getting what I need from the database and work on improvements going forward. This is all being done on localhost without a strict deadline. Thanks for your feedback to date!

Comment: We all started somewhere, don't fret too much over it.  But, do learn about SQL injection and how to prevent it (keyword: parameterized queries), and over time if you keep growing you will eventually understand the type of design MarcB is advocating.  What you have here is difficult to work with and maintain, but that's the kind of code we all write at the beginning :)

Comment: Thanks! I will not put anything online without protecting it from injection, I have a number of other pages working and have added escape string and strip slashes when I  have them functioning. Just trying to understand here why I am not producing the output I am after, and this has been a great forum so far!

Comment: no. you don't escape/strip.you're using mysqli - use placeholders.